# Webots Programming with python

Tags: python-2.7, webots

I am a Student in Newcastle University, currently undergoing my Master's Degree. My final project is a simulation using webots. I have to simulate a mobile robot, using python 2.7 coding. The problem is that I cannot find any documentation on python robot programming and the webots website has no python documentation. Everything in the website is based on C examples except from the names of some commands.
 Where can I find python documentation for webots in the internet? Or If anyone has documentation can they provide me with it? It will be very helpful for my project. 
Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: the problem is that i haven't used Python before and I do not know how to program sensors. I dont know where to look if what im doing is right or wrong. I dont know where to begin...

Comment: Learning Python before using Webots is very recommended.

Answer (score 4):

The complete Python API of the Webots controller module is described in the sections of this chapter:
https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/nodes-and-api-functions
For example: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/accelerometer?tab=python#wb_accelerometer_enable

In Webots, the Python API is exactly the same as the C++ oriented-object API, and the link with the C API is one-to-one too. So "translating" a Webots controller written in C / C++ to Python is often straight forward.

General instructions about programming a Webots controller (written for C) are true for Python too: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/controller-programming

Webots contains several Python examples, including:

- `$WEBOTS_HOME/resources/templates/controllers/template.py` (The template used when creating a new Python controller, reading the comments there should help you.)
- `$WEBOTS_HOME/projects/languages/python/...` (a demo to study showing how to control a robot, communicate between robots, do Supervisor tasks, get the Computer keyboard, etc.)

Note also that all the benchmarks of [robotbenchmark](https://robotbenchmark.net/) are written in Python and are using the Webots API (it could be a very good starting point to perform some of these benchmarks).